# How to plot inequality equations associated with a linear programming function

Tags: matlab, plot, inequality

I'm fairly new to Matlab, but have some basic understanding of programming principles.

I would like to plot the two variables, H (x-axis) vs. C (y-axis) following these two inequality equations: 4H+C<=20 and H+3C<=10, given: NB=H+2C (linear objective function vector), which are solved using the linprog function tool in Matlab (x=linprog(f,A,b);)

I know how to input the linprog programming (note here negative values for f are because I want to maximize, and not minimize my objective function):

```
f=[-1,-2];
A=[4 1; 1 3];
b=[20;10];
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = linprog(f,A,b);
```

which gives the optimal solution at x = (4.5455, 1.8182)

I would like to show this graphically, i.e. plot both inequality equations on a graph with both axis scales going from 0 to 10 using intervals of 1, but I cannot seem to make this work.

Here is what I have:

```
[H,C] = meshgrid((0:1:10),(0:1:10));
figure, hold on
xlabel('H, Hydropower')
ylabel('C, Crops')
```

The first problem is that it plots from 0-1 using intervals of 0.1 (??)
And of course, there are no lines representing the inequalities. But how to create the inequality lines?

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Urs

Comment: if you know you want to plot (say) 100 lines, then create equalities with offset of 100 different sizes. Then plot all 100 lines. Or you could plot a patch (see matlab help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is generating the whole NB and then deleting the parts that do not fill the conditions. Here you have a piece of code that does that (plus some fancy plotting). Remember, to plot the lines where the condition is in the "boundary" you neet to delete de inequality and put an equality (see code).

[image]

```
clear;clc
%Generate data
[H,C] = meshgrid(0:0.1:10);
NB=H+2*C;

% Get True where condition aplies, false where not.
cond1=4*H+C<=20;
cond2=H+3*C<=10;
% Get boundaries of the condition
Cp1=20-4*H(1,:);
Cp2=(10-H(1,:))/3;

%Delete Areas whereCondition does not apply;
NB(~cond1)=NaN;
NB(~cond2)=NaN;
%% Plot
[C,h]=contourf(H,C,NB,20);
clabel(C,h,'LabelSpacing',100) % optional
hold on


plot(H(1,:),Cp1,'r')

text(H(1,45),Cp1(45), '\leftarrow Cond1'); %arbitrary location

plot(H(1,:),Cp2,'k')
text(H(1,75),Cp2(75), '\leftarrow Cond2'); %arbitrary location


axis([0 10 0 10])
xlabel('H, Hydropower')
ylabel('C, Crops')
```

Comment: The only part of the code that I didn't understand concerns the setting of the conditional boundaries: Cp1=20-4*H(1,:);
Cp2=(10-H(1,:))/3; You solved for C in both equations (changing the inequality to an equality for plotting as you mentioned). What is the role of the (1,:) that is associated with variable 'H'? This would mean row 1, all columns typically, but I don't understand it in this context. And thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh, and the purpose behind using view(2), as commenting it out seemed to make no difference.

Comment: @Urs I did use `H(1,:)` because that is `0:0.1:10`, so I didnt need to create a new variable, for the `x` axis of the line plots. And indeed, I had that `view(2)` because I was using `surf` and I forgot to take it off when I changed. Good one!

Comment: @Urs Consider accepting the answer if you liked it ;)

Comment: @Urs http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work